# Click statistics with Twitter's t.co URL shortener?

Tags: twitter, url-shortening

Now that Twitter automatically shortens urls with its t.co service, 3rd party services like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) / [j.mp](http://j.mp) have become somewhat superfluous (for Twitter use).

However, bit.ly provides nice click stats for each shortened link ([example](https://bitly.com/p5eLcP+)). **Is there anything similar available for t.co shortened links?** (I've tried the bit.ly way of appending `+` to the url to get to the info/stats page, but that, at least, does not work.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't look like Twitter provides any additional services other than URL shortening, but this can change fast. In the meantime, I use the Google shortener [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) - great analytics, same as their usual web analytics. It uses your Google ID btw, although you can use it signed out (and give up the analytics)

Comment: When creating goo.gl shortlinks while being logged out, shortlinks still have some analytics, just append a + or .info to the shortlink to see it. Plus, in logged-out mode shortlinks are deterministic, so shortening the same link will always result in the identical shortlink.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://ads.twitter.com/ and login using your Twitter account. Go to *Analytics* → *Timeline Activity*.

Comment: Does your answer pertain to regular t.co links that you see in your timeline or Promoted tweets? I did not find any Analytics link after I logged into https://ads.twitter.com/ for the first time.

Comment: works only if the t.co linked tweet is tweeted by you