# Twitter URL shortening not deterministic?

Tags: twitter, url, url-shortening

These two Twitter shortened URLs

1. https://t.co/A8taVSsehm
2. https://t.co/eA7EpUqmgJ

both refer to the same target URL:

http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/audi-chef-rupert-stadler-festgenommen-a-1213533.html

I wonder, why that is. Would it not be more reasonable for Twitter to have only one shortened URL per target URL?

Comment: Probably Twitter adds tweet's author info to short link to get some statistics, see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49484

Comment: That sounds very plausible to me! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since Twitter measures each Tweet's activity including link clicks, a short link needs to be specific to a Tweet. Therefore the same URL can have different short links.

Here is an [explanation](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/url-shortener) from Twitter:

> Why does Twitter have its own link shortener?
>
> 2. Our link service measures information such as how many times a link has been clicked, which is an important quality signal in determining
>      how relevant and interesting each Tweet is when compared to
>      similar Tweets.